# Datatable issue with repeat

Tags: visualforce, datatable

I have 2 objects Agreement__c(Parent) and section__c(child) with a relationship name Agreement_Section. I'm trying to build a pdf with datatable iterate of child records but not able to relate the objects and getting the error 'Invalid field name Title__c'.

Here is my code:

Vf page:

```
 <table width="100%" class="table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Title</th>
                <th> Summary </th>
                <th> sample score</th>
                <th> sample  Percentage </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <apex:repeat value="{!Agreementrecords.Agreement_section__r}" var="a">

                    <tr>
                        <td><apex:outputText value="{!a.Title__c}"/></td>
                        <td><apex:outputText value="{!a.summary__c}"/></td>
                        <td><apex:outputText value="{!a.sample_score__c}"/></td>
                        <td><apex:outputText value="{!a.sample_Percentage__c}"/></td>

                    </tr>
          </apex:repeat>  
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Apex Controller:

```
public List<Review_by_Agency__c> getAgreementrecords(){
List<Agreement__c> Agreementrecords = [Select Name, (select Id, Name,   Title__c,
                                              summary__c,sample_Score__c,sample_percentage__c 
                                               from Agreement_Sections__r) from Agreement__c where ID= :RecordID];
return Agreementrecords;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the collection that the repeat iterates over needs to be the same name that appears in the relationship query in the controller. Also there are two collections: the collection of `Agreement__c` and each of those can have a collection of `Agreement_Section__c` so two repeats are needed. (You will need to experiment on how you want to present those: one table as show below or multiple tables.)

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Agreementrecords}" var="a">
    <apex:repeat value="{!a.Agreement_Sections__r}" var="s">
        <tr>
           <td><apex:outputText value="{!a.Name}"/></td>
           <td><apex:outputText value="{!s.Title__c}"/></td>
           <td><apex:outputText value="{!s.summary__c}"/></td>
           <td><apex:outputText value="{!s.sample_score__c}"/></td>
           <td><apex:outputText value="{!s.sample_Percentage__c}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

(I'm assuming here that the controller does compile meaning that the query has been verified by the Apex compiler.)

Comment: Getting error like 'Error: Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Agreement_Sections__r'  I made sure all collection is similar

Comment: @SalesforceLearner I'd missed that there are two collections - see updated answer.